# Is this the proper way using no punctuation marks between names?

Tags: culture

[image]

As shown in the picture, there is not even a stop or a mark between the names of so many people. If it is in the title, it might be for space efficience, but in the body, why is it still so arranged? Is there any implication for that?

Answer (score 2):

In modern Chinese, there should be a comma between names. It is just for practical reasons. A list of names without space in between is hard to read and often causes confusion

For example:

張進華文浩 can be 張進，華文浩 or 張進華，文浩

> Is there any implication for that?

Just bad formatting

Comment: I would use 頓號、，習近平、李強、趙樂際...

Comment: 頓號 is usually used when there is a list of items. Using commas between names gives more separation between the individuals (address them one by one instead of treating the names as a list of items) e.g. [名單上有: 習近平、李強、趙樂際]; [習近平，李強，趙樂際都去了]

Comment: Is it likely that all these people whose names are provided one by one without one being missing are at the same level or part of the same bloc so their names are strung together as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

The entire part between 【】 is a single long title. See the formatting of today's 人民日报: http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2023-11/03/nw.D110000renmrb_20231103_1-01.htm

Within news titles, it is convention not to have punctuation between person names.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that the format is hard to read and unprofessional looking (an opinion of a guy who worked in the advertising and publishing field)

Comment: A title (header) usually has no punctuation because it is usually short. I've never seen a paragraph-long title before

Comment: It doesn't strike me as odd. This format is consistently used by 新华社 and 人民日报. Two days ago there was 中央金融工作会议 and the title was " 赵乐际王沪宁蔡奇丁薛祥李希出席"

Comment: It doesn't help 新华社 and 人民日报 's reputation. 李克强同志遗体在京火化 is the header, the rest is a sub-header and it is too long, most of it should go to the main text. By the way, I don't follow Chinese news and can't tell 王沪宁蔡奇 is 王沪, 宁蔡奇 or 王沪宁, 蔡奇